# VBA Row Looping formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to loop code from cell directly in a macro. But all the return values in the AD column are `#NAME?`. How can I fix this?

Note that my Column refer to `K-Column` which has Date value in a form like this: `24/6/2015  6:54:00 AM` for example.

```
For PRow = lrow To 2 Step -1
    CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").Value = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(R[0]C[-19]), _ 
    ""/"",TEXT(MONTH(R[0]C[-19]),""00""))"
Next PRow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the R[]C[] Notation you need to add the value like this:

```
CurrentSheet.Cells(PRow, "AD").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(YEAR(R[0]C[-19]), ""/"",TEXT(MONTH(R[0]C[-19]),""MM""))"
```

Comment: did you mean to write `TEST(...` or `TEXT(...`??

Comment: @IlhamideaZ Look at my edit, i tried an example and that seems to work. let me know if that is what you where looking for?!

Comment: OK, typo, my fault >< Thanks @marco-getrost ! :)